# PHP arrays neighbors

Tags: php, arrays

I need a little help. I don't want code or the solution, only a guide of HOW do it.

If I have a array:

```
$array = [[9, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5], [9, 8, 3, 2, 4, 5], [9, 7, 2, 2, 4, 3], [9, 9, 2, 4, 4, 3], [9, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]];
```

And I have to return

```
$return = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]];
```

The logic is:
If index has a neighbors less than him, is 0, otherwise is 1.

Thanks everything!

Comment: Use nested loops.

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide any more detailed "HOW" without actually writing the code.

Comment: Yep nested loops with a little bit of if/else does the trick here

Comment: `foreach - for - if - change value`

Comment: And how i do that if? I recorred every array, but i do'nt how make this if :(

Comment: We cant explain it more without writing code lol. You do the if part with comparing $array[$i][$current] with $array[$i][$current + 1] (where $current is your iterator in the second loop). But check beforehand if there is a next element in the array (with isset e.g)

Comment: I tried but i don't get the second array with +1 and whatever. I think that I need code in this part lol :( i'm so dumb today

Comment: Are you wanting a recursive function as the answer? Because that could be an addition I think everyone is overlooking that might be wanted in the answer, assuming this is a homework problem.

Comment: Additionally, there is a way to reduce the number of checks that you actually do. What I mean is that you don't have to look left and right for every index. It just involves a little extra logic.

Comment: @carlos  if you are going to compare both side then this will output:-https://eval.in/621918

Answer (score 2):

Make two for loops, one inside the other.

The first for loop will loop over `$array` and give you an index, let's call it `$i`.

The second for loop will iterate over the elements of each of the arrays in side `$array`, looping over `$array[$i]`.